# How to do a 64-bit write in C?

Tags: c

I want to know how I can write 64-bit values into memory in C. I'm doing embedded development and in order for something to function areas of memory must be initialized using 64-bit writes.

Comment: Which CPU and compiler? i.e. do you have 64-bit registers or are you going to have to fake this somehow? Do you have a 64-bit int type e.g. in [stdint.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html)?

Comment: @Rup so you interpret the question to mean that OP wants atomic writes?

Comment: @David I assumed "using 64bit writes" meant "writing 64bits of data in a single operation", yes. He said embedded so I assume this is a memory mapped device and they can have odd requirements. (And if that's not what he means then it's not a very interesting question!)

Comment: @David In embedded development an area of memory that "must be initialised using 64bit writes" is a common problem, and is probably not normal memory. It may not have byte lanes or it may be ECC memory which hasn't been initialised yet. This doesn't help us answer, as the question doesn't state which platform and compiler.

Comment: @Adrian @Rup Thanks, I'm now more educated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void write_64bit_zero_to(void *address)
{
  *((uint64_t *) address) = 0;
}
```

if your platform doesn't provide `stdint.h`, I'm sure it has something similiar as long as the architecture actually supports 64-bit integers (which, of course, you've said that it does). See [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/uint64_t) for more talk about the type.

Comment: @Adrian you are correct its not main memory and it is ECC that i am trying to set up. The compiler is gcc and platform is mips

Comment: @JohnB your comment doesn't make a whole lot of sense. :)